# unable to perform a right-click --> deploy on azure function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-standard

I'm attempting to publish my azure function from visual studio, by right clicking on the `project-->deploy` and then selecting `publish`.

I get the following exception:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.502\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(139,5): error : Web deployment task failed. (Web Deploy cannot modify the file 'AAAUtilities.dll' on the destination because it is locked by an external process.  In order to allow the publish operation to succeed, you may need to either restart your application to release the lock, or use the AppOffline rule handler for .Net applications on your next publish attempt.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FILE_IN_USE.) [C:\tfs\CCC\AAA\AAAUtilities\DEV\AAAUtilities\AAAUtilities.csproj]
>         Publish failed to deploy.

**What am I doing incorrectly?**

- Visual studio is opened as administrator
- Project builds locally and I am able to run it locally
- I've also downloaded the publish profile from the portal, in order to use for deployment, and that yielded the same exception

Comment: Does it work if you take the app offline first?

Comment: Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes#errorfileinuse

Comment: yes, it worked after i took it offline, but i dont want to have to take it offline every time

Comment: Understood but if the current application is using a dll that needs to be replaced then there is no other way to release the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Offline is a feature that takes our app offline when deploying, in order to avoid the issue of locking dlls as you have seen. After the deployment is finished, our app will start automatically.

We can configure the appOffline rule in the publishing profile (In Solution explorer> Properties>PublishProfiles>*.pubxml). Set the EnableMSDeployAppOffline to true as below.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <EnableMSDeployAppOffline>true</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>
  ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

There's another way to deploy--[Run From Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package#benefits-of-running-from-a-package-file), which can free us from locking dlls as well. We can see the checkbox of it when creating a new publish profile. Note that it also causes restart as well.

[image: rfp]